# Cholesky factor. Matrix is not positive definite

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, covariance-matrix

I have a variance-covariance matrix as part of my optimization problem, and I want to get the Cholesky factor.
The parameters that I am trying to estimate in the optimization are standard deviations of 7 variables and the correlation coefficient between the 7 variables.

```
# The first eight values are irrevalent (which is another part for my optimization problem). 
# These values are initiated by scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.
params = np.array([ 0.7806441 ,  0.43681974,  0.44591321,  0.40755392,  0.95581486,
        0.45218698,  0.72242087,  0.10477314,  0.49510088,  0.46714018,
        0.06582374,  0.11473761,  0.07053657,  0.4480119 ,  0.47490398,
       -0.58165201,  0.80810424, -0.42242146,  0.16330766,  0.88495337,
       -0.73821011,  0.82768099,  0.66367593, -0.84882425,  0.51292046,
       -0.78708664, -0.97173908,  0.5514854 , -0.1384802 , -0.00899825,
        0.55532738,  0.4374165 ,  0.63025894,  0.75539676, -0.08648026,
        0.40995866])


# standard errors params[8:15], bounded between 0 and 0.5
# because the variable is between 0 and 1. 
# I have 7 variables, so here each element in 'dev' is the sd of one variable.
dev = np.diag(params[8:15]) 

# correlation coefficients params[15:35], bounded between -1 and 1. 
# params[15:21]: rho11, rho12, ... rho17.
corr1 = np.insert(params[15:21],0,1.0)

# params[21:26]: rho23, rho24, ... rho27.
corr2 = np.insert(np.concatenate((np.zeros(1), params[21:26])), 1, 1.0)
corr3 = np.insert(np.concatenate((np.zeros(2), params[26:30])), 2, 1.0)
corr4 = np.insert(np.concatenate((np.zeros(3), params[30:33])), 3, 1.0)
corr5 = np.insert(np.concatenate((np.zeros(4), params[33:35])), 4, 1.0)
corr6 = np.insert(np.concatenate((np.zeros(5), params[35:36])), 5, 1.0)
corr7 = np.append(np.zeros(6), 1.0)

X=np.vstack((corr1,corr2,corr3,corr4,corr5,corr6,corr7))
X = X + X.T - np.diag(np.diag(X))
cov = dev.dot(X).dot(dev)

L = np.linalg.cholesky(cov)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/3.9/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 779, in cholesky
    r = gufunc(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
  File "/Library/Python/3.9/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 115, in _raise_linalgerror_nonposdef
    raise LinAlgError("Matrix is not positive definite")
numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Matrix is not positive definite

# check egienvalues
print(np.linalg.eigvalsh(cov))
[-0.22219591 -0.00343992  0.00541225  0.0116191   0.27866962  0.38321562
  0.45878541]
```

Why does my variance-covariance matrix `cov` has negative egienvalues? Where did I do wrong?

Comment: Why should it be positive? We don't know were your parameter come from. Do you have a reason to believe that built as such, `cov` is positive definite? That it is a covariance matrix? (I mean, it is symmetric, sure, since you built it with a `X+X.T-diag`. But not all symmetric matrices are covariance matrices and positive definite.

Comment: @chrslg. I am doing optimization. `params` are the variables that I am estimating using scipy.optimize.differential_evolution, so these values are given by scipy.optimize.differential_evolution. I also have specified bounds for the standard deviation (0-0.5) for the variables ranging between 0 and 1, and correlation coefficients have bounds (-1.0, 1.0). So I think I should be getting a correct `cov` which is at least positive semidefinite.

Comment: But what are you optimizing? There are two things I don't understand here. 1st is because I don't know what you are optimizing. So maybe it would make sense if I knew. But I don't know why we should trust that `params` are a valid set of stdev and correlations coefficients (not all sets of values are). But, well, may be your optimization is done in such a way that it guarantees that (for example because your are optimzing some linear combination of vectors that make them idependent)

Comment: And the 2nd, is harder to understand (because this times, contrarily to your optimization, I see the code, and I still don't get it), is how `X+X.T-diag` is supposed to be a valid correlation matrix (well, with the stdev afterward, but that would be the same with a base change), I really have a hard time imagining a process that produces values such as when you combine them in this strange `X+X.T-diag` way, they happen to produce correlation coefficients. It is not impossible sure. But seems very unnatural

Comment: Note that it is probably me who don't get something. That piece of code just seems strange, but that only prove that I don't know the logic behind it. But in the other hand, it is a fact that those values, to which I say "I don't get how can we know that they end up being a valid covariance matrix" happen to not be a valid covariance matrix" (and correlations coefficient to works with cholesky. And when they don't, because of numerical error, it is certainly not with some `-2` eigenvalues. With a `-0.01` eigenvalues it could have been possible to point to numerical error, but -2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since any covariance matrix is [guaranteed to be positive definite](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52976/is-a-sample-covariance-matrix-always-symmetric-and-positive-definite), I went looking for ways in which this covariance matrix contained some kind of mistake or internal contradiction.

The first thing I looked at was this line:

```
cov = dev.dot(X).dot(dev)
```

Although this line looked suspicious to me, I coded an alternative implementation which multiplies standard error along rows and columns, and it agrees with this line.

The second thing I looked at was the correlation coefficient matrix. Although correlation is not, in general, transitive, for sufficiently strong correlation, it does [obey some transitive properties](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181376/is-correlation-transitive).

Using the inequality in the linked question, I looked for contradictions among the correlation coefficients. Here is the correlation matrix, X, before multiplying in the standard deviations.

```
[[ 1.         -0.58165201  0.80810424 -0.42242146  0.16330766  0.88495337 -0.73821011]
 [-0.58165201  1.          0.82768099  0.66367593 -0.84882425  0.51292046 -0.78708664]
 [ 0.80810424  0.82768099  1.         -0.97173908  0.5514854  -0.1384802  -0.00899825]
 [-0.42242146  0.66367593 -0.97173908  1.          0.55532738  0.4374165   0.63025894]
 [ 0.16330766 -0.84882425  0.5514854   0.55532738  1.          0.75539676 -0.08648026]
 [ 0.88495337  0.51292046 -0.1384802   0.4374165   0.75539676  1.          0.40995866]
 [-0.73821011 -0.78708664 -0.00899825  0.63025894 -0.08648026  0.40995866  1.        ]]
```

In this matrix, the correlation between 1 and 2 is 0.82768099. The correlation between 2 and 0 is 0.80810424. By the inequality in the linked question, the correlation between 0 and 1 must be positive. But it's negative. The program I wrote finds many other problems like this one. This set of correlations is not possible, and the result is that the covariance matrix is not possible either.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# The first eight values are irrevalent (which is another part for my optimization problem). 
# These values are initiated by scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.
params = np.array([ 0.7806441 ,  0.43681974,  0.44591321,  0.40755392,  0.95581486,
        0.45218698,  0.72242087,  0.10477314,  0.49510088,  0.46714018,
        0.06582374,  0.11473761,  0.07053657,  0.4480119 ,  0.47490398,
       -0.58165201,  0.80810424, -0.42242146,  0.16330766,  0.88495337,
       -0.73821011,  0.82768099,  0.66367593, -0.84882425,  0.51292046,
       -0.78708664, -0.97173908,  0.5514854 , -0.1384802 , -0.00899825,
        0.55532738,  0.4374165 ,  0.63025894,  0.75539676, -0.08648026,
        0.40995866])


# standard errors params[8:15], bounded between 0 and 0.5
# because the variable is between 0 and 1. 
dev = params[8:15]

# correlation coefficients params[15:35], bounded between -1 and 1. 
corr1 = np.insert(params[15:21],0,1.0)
corr2 = np.insert(np.concatenate((np.zeros(1), params[21:26])), 1, 1.0)
corr3 = np.insert(np.concatenate((np.zeros(2), params[26:30])), 2, 1.0)
corr4 = np.insert(np.concatenate((np.zeros(3), params[30:33])), 3, 1.0)
corr5 = np.insert(np.concatenate((np.zeros(4), params[33:35])), 4, 1.0)
corr6 = np.insert(np.concatenate((np.zeros(5), params[35:36])), 5, 1.0)
corr7 = np.append(np.zeros(6), 1.0)

X=np.vstack((corr1,corr2,corr3,corr4,corr5,corr6,corr7))
X = X + X.T - np.diag(np.diag(X))
np.set_printoptions(edgeitems=30, linewidth=100000)
print(X)


def sign(x):
    if x > 0:
        return 1
    elif x < 0:
        return -1
    else:
        raise Exception()


for corr_idx_x in range(7):
    for corr_idx_y in range(corr_idx_x + 1, 7):
        for corr_idx_z in range(7):
            if len(set((corr_idx_x, corr_idx_y, corr_idx_z))) != 3:
                # Skip duplicate correlation indexes
                continue
            corr_val_xy = X[corr_idx_x, corr_idx_y]
            corr_val_yz = X[corr_idx_y, corr_idx_z]
            corr_val_zx = X[corr_idx_z, corr_idx_x]
            if corr_val_yz ** 2 + corr_val_zx ** 2 > 1:
                condition = "anything"
                if sign(corr_val_yz) == sign(corr_val_zx):
                    condition = "positive"
                elif -1 * sign(corr_val_yz) == sign(corr_val_zx):
                    condition = "negative"
                
                print_it = False
                if condition == "positive" and corr_val_xy < 0:
                    print_it = True
                elif condition == "negative" and corr_val_xy > 0:
                    print_it = True
                if print_it:
                    print(f"Correlation between {corr_idx_y} and {corr_idx_z} is {corr_val_yz}")
                    print(f"Correlation between {corr_idx_z} and {corr_idx_x} is {corr_val_zx}")
                    print(f"Therefore, correlation between {corr_idx_x} and {corr_idx_y} must be {condition}, actually {corr_val_xy}")
                    print()
```

Comment: Then I think I will need to write some constraints for the optimization. Thanks!